# URLs for asynchronous and asynchronous requests in zend framwork

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, routes

I have a problem when sending asynchronous request to server, the url of server append to the  current url and so the url will be incorrect!

I have anchors that send synchronous get request to controller using this way

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('module'=>'visits','controller'=>'visit','action'=>'index', 'page'=>'add'),NULL,TRUE); ?>" class="addVisit">Add new visit</a>
```

when I click over it the url becomes

```
 http://inspectionsys/visits/visit/index/page/add
```

When I click on another button that send asynchronous request to server using ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "visit/get-visits",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: requestDate,
    success: successCallback,
    error:failureCallback
});
```

the URL becomes like this

```
http://inspectionsys/visits/visit/index/page/visit/get-visits
```

The url must be like this

```
http://inspectionsys/visits/visit/get-visits
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is being appended because you are using a relative link instead of an absolute one. Change your ajax call to this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/visit/get-visits",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: requestDate,
    success: successCallback,
    error:failureCallback
});
```

(note the leading slash on the URL).

Comment: It works when I specify the module too "/visits/visit/get-visits", thank you